# What is best practice to constantly receive coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, alamofire

I am kind of new to programming and wanted to know what would be the best way to get data from server? To be more specific my app receives GPS coordinates from server (currently using Alamofire) and then shows them on the map.

Now, I don't know how keep those coordinates updated on device. Should I make loop, where app downloads coordinates from server, let's say, every 5 seconds and shows them on the map? Should loop interval be longer? Ideally I would like if an app could show live location - that is get updates from server every second.

Maybe there is library for my specific problem? Where could I read more about this?

And I could upload some of my code, but now it simply get data in`viewDidLoad` using Alamofire and show it on map.

**EDIT:** Why do I keep getting down votes? Seriuosly, I would like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: As for why you keep getting downvotes, have a look through the Help Center section on [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) questions. As contrary as it sounds, people tend to like questions they don't have to think too much about ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to use socket programming and listen particular socket where coordinates will be pushed from server. Rather than pulling periodically this will be push mechanism where server will push from it's side whenever it has new coordinate available ...

Here is the Apple's guide line for the same

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW4

If this seems like too much you can use pubnub library for ios which is free for 100 devices

Here is the link

https://www.pubnub.com/

Comment: Which parts of OP's question were you trying to address?

Comment: My question, had many questions, but main part is the best practise to get updates from server and socket programming seems like the solution (I am currently reading more about it)